# WCF: Required properties are not really required

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

There is some stange behaviour, that a can't get with the IsRequired option.

Let's say, there is a very small DataContract:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class CommonEvent
  {
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

When i start my WebService and reference it, I'll get the followed xsd:

```
  <xs:complexType name="CommonEvent">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

But this XSD does not require Name... I've read an advice to add `XmlElement(IsNullable = true)` to tha name, but this does not solve the problem as well, as the definition of the Name will de as followed: `<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />`, but it still does not require any value.
My expectation for required value would be like this: `<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />` (default for nillable is "false").

What is wrong with my definition? (or understanding?)

Comment: `IsNullable = true` means that it can be null. `IsNullable = false` means it cannot be null and is required.

Comment: The question was about required filds in DataCantact, which are defined as followed: `<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />` in spite of `IsRequired = true`. 

And related to `IsNullable = false`, I've read somewhere, that it's a workaround to make `minOccurs="1" ` (instead of `minOccurs="0" `) could be a set `IsNullable = true` (to get `minOccurs="1" `) but it does not make value required.

Comment: The IsRequired flag in the DataContract is for validation, so you should be able to receive request with the the field omitted, but it should throw an exception when processing, which you would handle in your code.

Comment: This is for server side validation. Client side validation you would have to write yourself.

Comment: Yes, and would like to have this validation. But it does not work! In my case, when i send an object without Name (Name is null), then there is no validation exception (on server). An my suggestion, that there is no exception, because `minOccurs` for Name is 0.

Comment: Working as documented - as stated in [DataContractVersioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-versioning#required-data-members) _"Although the IsRequired property is set to true, the incoming data may be null or zero, and a type must be prepared to handle this possibility. Do not use IsRequired as a security mechanism to protect against bad incoming data."_